# Highest runs that a batsman can score in an over?

Tags: cricket

Assuming there are no overthrows and no extras (like no-balls, wide balls, etc), what is the highest a batsman score in an over?

**UPDATE:**
If the ball first hits the bat, then the helmet and goes for a boundary, he will score 5+4 =9 runs/ball. So, in an over, 9*6 = 54 runs. Is this logic correct?

Comment: I don't know if he gets 9 (5+4) runs in one ball. But if I am a captain, and if the ball touches the helmet back to back (or twice), I will send the helmet into the pavilion!

Comment: @hims056 hehe yeah...but it is possible..may be!

Comment: The 5 runs for hitting the helmet are penalty runs.  They don't go to the batsman's personal score.

Comment: I don't 9 runs is possible.theoretically,consider this scenario, the batsmen has already ran 6 max possible(if ball not last) then the fielder throws the ball on to the helmet , the ball gets deflected and reaches the boundary then according to you the team would get 6+5+4=15 runs. I guess the ball will be called dead once it touches the helmet

Comment: @gout "_Assuming there are no overthrows and no extras (like no-balls, wide balls, etc)_" in the question.

Comment: without over throws you will still get 11 runs

Comment: Penalty runs are also classed as extras, and as @PeterEisentraut points out, they do not count towards the batsman's score. Therefore 6*6 = 36 runs would be the maximum a batsman could score from a 6-ball over, without overthrows or running more than 6.

Comment: Farfiekld Sobers once scored 36 runs in a county match in England. He hit 6 sixes off an off spin bowler.

Comment: i can say that jaques kallis hetted si sixes in one over

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number of runs you can score of a single delivery is in principle unlimited, because the batsmen can keep running forever.  This was especially possible before the introduction of current Lost Ball rule, for example when the ball got stuck in a tree.

Comment: I am not sure, I could follow you properly. How can a batsman get unlimited run of a single delivery?

Comment: @Mistu4u - there is no limit to the number of runs the batsmen can run between the wickets, as long as someone doesn't run them out - 6 is not a limit.  This was especially true before the Lost Ball rule - some grounds have trees within the boundary, where a ball could theoretically get lost in.  For most circumstances however 6 runs is the limit per ball.

Answer (score 2):

If all balls are fair there will be 6 balls in the over. If one batter faces all of these and gets the maximum score possible each ball, which is 6 runs for hitting the ball on the full over the boundary, then they will score 36 runs in the over.

Comment: If the ball does not cross the boundary, _however unlikely_, is it possible for the batsmen to run more than 6 runs off one delivery?

Comment: True, it is possible, though the exclusion of overthrows makes it even less likely. However I guess you're right, if all 11 players in the fielding side spontaneously break their legs running for the ball the batsmen could, in theory, keep running for ever....

Comment: I think the relevant rules are here http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs,44,AR.html I can't see anything that limits the number of runs scored by running between wickets, so yes I think you're correct, you could in theory score more than 6 runs in a ball in this way.

Comment: @Orangecrush see update

Comment: And yeah,not those kind of tricks,running forever and stuff..

Answer (score -2):

i think so that there can be 48 made in a single over...four run by running nd while running the fourth run if filder overthrow nd it goes out for boundry then by ths way there is 8 runs per ball and 8*6=48

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question specifies that "there are no overthrows."